# Multiple Pie chart with based on multiple ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, highcharts

Hi I want 3 pie chart next to each other based on the different dataset. The first chart will be based on one ajax call the second one will be based on the other ajax call and the third chart will be based on the third ajax call. How do i plot such graph using Highchart.js kindly help i am new in this.

Comment: The concepts is, create an ajax request, return `json` format from server side, populating chart using `highchart` configuration. Configuration already there, and they also provide `jsfiddle` for demonstration.

Comment: Please share your code @Manish

Comment: Can you please provide some sample code for at least 2 ajax request and plotting the graph with the returend data , as i am absolutely new in this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I give sample of `events` option of cart to make ajax request for data
on initialization.Your question how to make multiple chart based on multiple request. So here I make two container (container1 and container1) as

```
<div id="container1" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
<div id="container2" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

And initialize two chart `chart1 and chart2` in js

```
$(function () {
  var chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
        renderTo: 'container1',
          type: 'pie',
          events: {
            load: requestDataforChart1
          }
        },
        title: {
            text: 'data for chart1'
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                allowPointSelect: true,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
                    style: {
                        color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
        }]
    });
var chart2 = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
        renderTo: 'container2',
            type: 'pie',
            events: {
                load: requestDataforChart2
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: 'data for chart 2'
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                allowPointSelect: true,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
                    style: {
                        color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
        }]
    });

 function requestDataforChart1() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'get_url.php',
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        data : {chart : "pie1"},
        success: function(data) {
            chart1.addSeries({
              name: 'Brands',
                colorByPoint: true,
              data: data.data_for_pie1
            });
        },
        cache: false
    });
}
 function requestDataforChart2() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'get_url.php',
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        data : {chart : "pie2"},
        success: function(data) {
            chart2.addSeries({
              name: 'Brands',
                colorByPoint: true,
              data: data.data_for_pie2
            });
        },
        cache: false
    });
}
});
```

This two chart make ajax request with there `events` and in each of the ajax response will add data to respective chart through `addSeries`.

I hope this will give some idea how to **multiple chart based on multiple request**

Comment: Thanks a lot Deep.

Comment: is  above sample code is the  solution of current question and detailed solution for [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41929450)

Comment: Yes Deep the above sample code is the good reference for me. But the three pie chart is taking long time to display do you have any idea on this.

Comment: from one ajax call get the data for the three chart. based on the key of the incoming data array ,populate each pie chart (key,value pair in data array)

Comment: Hi Deep how to acheive this- Clicking on a portion of the doughnut charts will filter by that item. in the attached image  when the geographical dispersion chart on the left is clicked on
the Australian portion of the chart. The chart on the right is after the chart has been clicked

Comment: Kindly refer this url for the image https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fmn5W.png

Comment: There is chart called drilldown in highcharts. use it  .it has built in feature you are looking for

Comment: I had an issue with the pie chart where in when charts loads and when i click on any portion of the chart the whole chart loads again . how to avoid it loading on every click. Please suggest

Comment: Ask a new question and give proper details